# How to import Readability modules in content script for Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm using webpack and trying to import into the content script of an extension,

```
import Readability from "@mozilla/readability";
```

it does not work, I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at content.js:1:1)

I've tried to add the file directly to manifest and include type module into the manifest,

```
 "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["dist/content.bundle.js", "Readability.js"],
        
        "type": "module"
      }
```